# How to read words with variable length from a text file and adding them to a list in C

Tags: c, list, file, pointers, singly-linked-list

I have to create a function that receives in input the name of a file, which contains words in a casual order, and it has to return a pointer to a list where every node contains a pointer to each word. How can I do?

```
typedef struct _NODE {
char* word;
struct _NODE *next;
} NODE;
```

I tried to implement this

```
NODE* createFromFile(char* nameFile)
{
    FILE* ptr = fopen(nameFile, "r");
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    NODE* n = NULL;
    NODE* temp= n;

    while (!feof(ptr))
    {
        char store[MAX_WORD];
        NODE* new = NULL;

        new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        new->word=fgets(store, MAX_WORD, ptr);
        new->next = NULL;

        if (n == NULL)
        {
            n = new;
            temp = n;
        }
        else
        {
             while (temp->next != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;

             temp->next = new;
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return n;
}
```

But if I implement the function that follows to print it, it prints random characters:

```
void printDictionary(NODO* dictionary)
{
    NODO* temp = dictionary;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", temp->word);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Help please

Comment: For each new word, you should strcpy() the read word into a buffer allocated separately for each node.

Comment: Could you write a piece of code please?

Comment: @Snorlite  This statement new->word=fgets(store, MAX_WORD, ptr); sets any pointer in the list to the same local array that  will not be alive after exiting the function. You have to make a copy of the array dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: Do not use `while (!feof(ptr))`, test the return value of `fgets()` to determine when to stop.  Who/what text suggested using `feof()`?

Comment: Basically, after fgets(store...), you do `new->word = malloc(strlen(store)); strcpy(new->word, store);`

Comment: @Snorlite  Write a separate function that adds new nodes to the list and call it from the function createFromFile. Take into account that if you have a singly-linked one-sided list then new nodes are added to the head of the list.

Comment: @linuxfan it's rather `new->word = malloc(strlen(store) + 1); strcpy(new->word, store);` (note the __+1__). YOu need one byte more for the `NUL` terminator.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, ty and sorry. `new->word = malloc(strlen(store)+1); strcpy(new->word, store);` (basically!)